# Is there any way to write a dataframe from azure databricks to azure data lake using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to write a dataframe from databricks to azure data lake gen2.

i'm having a dataframe which have 8 millions of records.

i'm using df..repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("header","true").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save('/mnt/abc/')

It's taking around 1/2 hours to write a file. Is there any better way to write the dataframe to ADLS?

Comment: Have you looked at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers ?